# Trouble running Typescript Unit Tests in Webstorm

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

I am trying to run Unit Tests for Typescript using tsUnit. I have included the tsUnit path. There seems to be something wrong with the way I've imported it.

```
 ///<reference path="tsUnit.ts" />

import testClass = tsUnit;

class IDTest extends tsUnit.TestClass {

    selectIDTest() {
        ...
        this.areIdentical("#" + id, idSelector);
    }

    setAsRootTest() {
        ...
        this.areIdentical("root", target.setAsRoot());
    }
}

var test = new tsUnit.Test();
test.addTestClass(new IDTest());

test.showResults(document.getElementById('results'), test.run());
```

Here's the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tsUnit is not defined  IDTest.ts:8:21
  (anonymous function)  IDTest.ts:8:21
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :    chrome-extension://mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf/shortcut_manager.js
  (anonymous function)  chrome-extension://mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf/shortcut_manager.js
  (anonymous function)  extensions::messaging
  target.(anonymous function)   extensions::SafeBuiltins
  Event.dispatchToListener  extensions::event_bindings
  Event.dispatch_   extensions::event_bindings
  Event.dispatch    extensions::event_bindings
  dispatchOnMessage extensions::messaging
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `import testClass = tsUnit;` is nothing more than a name alias i.e. `var testClass = tsUnit;` Does not do any importing whatsoever.

Given that you are using a manual reference `///<reference path="tsUnit.ts" />` compile using the `--out` flag and use a reference.ts to order your files : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#javascript-generation-and-ordering

Comment: Won't the --out flag compile everything into a single file? I wan't to maintain modularity by having the code compiled into separate .js files - one for each .ts test file. And I am using RequireJS for client JS files(as per your suggestion made in a previous question) instead of the --out flag, so if I change the settings for the test files, my settings for all files would be changed, won't it?

Comment: Can you suggest a commandline instruction to include only the contents of the tsUnit file into each individual tsUnit test file?